# Java resizing game

Tags: java, resize, jframe

I've been trying to learn game development in Java. So far I've been using JFrame `setResizable(false)`. It was good enough for me, but I want to take it one step further. I tried to make it fullscreen. So I would have to resize everything in my Canvas based of this:

```
float widthScale = screenWidth / canvasWidth;
```

and

```
float heightScale = screenHeight / canvasHeight;
```

So I'd multiply everything in Canvas with those scales. I know it's wrong.

How to use resizable `JFrame` in games properly without using any external libraries?

Comment: You have the right idea.  Anything in your game that's drawable on a Canvas or (preferably) a JPanel has to be scaled based on the size of the drawing panel.  What I did for a board game was create a BufferedImage that was the size I wanted (something like 5,000 x 5,000 pixels) and either crop (to show part of the full size board) or reduce the image to the size of the drawing panel.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that there is no easier way of doing it. I feel like a genius xD. Thanks

Comment: Here's an image of my [Stock Market Board Game](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3znHW.png).